# create org split agenda view, problems with differnt agendas in split windows

Tags: org-mode

I have written this crappy code (i cant really code) to save a split orgmode agenda views with different agenda views.

```
(defun z/buffers-restore-agenda-split   ()
 (interactive)    
 (org-agenda nil "a")
 (split-window-right)
 (org-agenda nil "ba")
 (split-window-below)
 (org-agenda nil "bb")
 )
```

the function does split the windows correctly yet all the views get the last option ("bb") instead of a different view in each window

any clue why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default behaviour of `org-agenda` is to *replace* the contents of the agenda buffer rather than making new agenda buffer.  You can change this by setting the variable `org-agenda-sticky`:

> Non-nil means agenda q key will bury agenda buffers.
>   Agenda commands will then show existing buffer instead of generating new ones.
>   When nil, ‘q’ will kill the single agenda buffer.

You can set this globally or just set it temporarily in your function using `let`:

```
(defun z/buffers-restore-agenda-split   ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-sticky t))
    (org-agenda nil "a")
    (split-window-right)
    (org-agenda nil "ba")
    (split-window-below)
    (org-agenda nil "bb")
    ))
```

Comment: perfect! this solves the issue

Comment: for some reason i pressed the down button and it wont let me undo that. in anycase the answer is perfect and solved. hope admins can up-vote it

Comment: You just have to wait a while before you can change your vote.

Comment: Upvoted for justice.